# p99 spikes in springboot api which communicates with MS AD

Tags: networking, docker, ldap, active-directory

dont know if this question belongs to unix.stackechange/stackoverflow/devops.stackexchange.

I open it here because i think it could be somehow unix/linux related.

We have a custom java/springboot api, running in a docker container on ubuntu, behind a WSO2 Apimanager, which wraps Active Directory Querys into REST calls.

What wee see is that ~1% of our requests are really really slow (~130 or ~260 seconds are the slow requests).
a point we see is that if its a slow request it takes everytime ~130 or ~260 seconds,
A log statement when this happens looks like this:

```
2021-05-11 14:56:55.114 5b86b59d-d4bf-447b-96fc-9256af8b6113;activemq-loginmodule;  INFO 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] at.<redacted>.commons.service.LoggingFilter  : method=GET, uri="/aduser/<ad-user>/roles?filters=api-*%2Cmq-*", response_status=200, remote_address=10.0.0.11, response_time_ms=130141, request_body="[empty]", header_x_forwarded_host="wso2-apimanager.domain.com", header_x_forwarded_proto="https", header_x_forwarded_port="443", header_x_forwarded_for="10.10.0.20", header_x_<redacted>_requestid="5b86b59d-d4bf-447b-96fc-9256af8b6113;activemq-loginmodule;", header_accept="application/json", header_host="ad-api.domain.com:8080", header_connection="Keep-Alive", header_user_agent="Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO", cookies=[empty], response_body="[empty]"
```

we enabled slow query log for ldap queries on our domaincontroller which communicates with our spring boot api, there we saw that the active directory is answering the queries fast (slowest queries about 2-3 seconds).

we digged then into with tcpdump on our ubuntu host which carries our API and saw the following:

AD Domaincontroller: 10.xx.xx.79

Linux Server which hosts our springboot api: 10.xx.xx.97
[image: slow api call]

[image: fast api call]

sow somehow it looks like our linux system which hosts our spring boot api or our springboot api itself, in rare cases does not send the unbind request to our ad ldap, so the api call hangs until 2 or 4 minutes later our server does the unbind.

What is really strange about this, is that we see this happening since 7 days, our springboot api hasn't changed since 3 months, so we did not change anything on api side when this started to happen..

**Why this happens? How we can find out why this happens? How we can dig into it deeper?**

Comment: 1. Have you tried increasing the log level of either java springboot api or your WSO2 Apimanager (note: i know literally nothing about either of those things so cannot offer any specific advice about them) ?  2. Is it, maybe, keeping the connection open to re-use for other requests (this is not an uncommon optimisation when there's significant overhead in starting/ending a tcp connection).

Comment: BTW, suitably edited `tcpdump` output would be more useful than a partial screenshot of wireshark.  Easier to redact, too.   See [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).